# Re-render in vegalite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to use vega lite to create an in-page graph renderer.

Oddly, I can't find any documentation on how to re-render a graph after updating the spec.

Am I missing a reference somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the spec, you need to compile again. You can just pass the new spec to Vega-Embed's `embed` method.